# Can xslt read or skip <beans:beans> tag?

Tags: xslt

I'm creating an XSLT file for XML which contains a tag `<beans:bean>`, probably from spring framework. Basically, the structure of the XML is as follows:

```
 <beans:beans>
   <fix>
       <message>
               important content
       </message>   
   </fix>
</beans:beans>
```

I can't find a way to get rid of the `<beans:beans>` tag, actually the relevant content for me is under the `message` tag.

Using `<xsl:for-each select="fix/message">` I am able to reach the content I need. However I have to remove the `<beans:beans>` tag manually

Is there a way to make XSLT skip or read the `<beans:beans>` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing certain XML elements via XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524786/removing-certain-xml-elements-via-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

This is idiomatically solved using the identity transform with an override:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:beans="http://someuri">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="beans:beans">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<root>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://someuri">
        <fix>
            <message>
                important content
            </message>
        </fix>
    </beans:beans>
</root>
```

Removes the unwanted element:

```
<root>
   <fix>
       <message>
               important content
       </message>   
   </fix>
</root>
```

Some notes:

- This copies everything in the file, unchanged, except the `beans:beans` element
- Your `beans` element has a namespace prefix. I have added a namespace URI to make this transformation work.
- Your stylesheet also needs to be aware of the namespace. Notice the use of `xmlns:beans="http://someuri"`. You'll need to modify this to map to the actual `beans` namespace.